# Can't find .env files during PHPUnit test using PUTTY

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant, putty

I'm using a vagrant box for my php project. I've created two .env files (.env and .env.testing). The website runs smoothly but while testing the functions using PHPUnit, it throws me a `File Not found` error. I can see the files on my directory but can't view them in terminal using `ls`. But I can see them all if I use `ls -a` command. Is the issue with vagrant or putty or am I doing this wrong?